# Getting Error When I Start multiple select query inside loop TimeoutError: ResourceRequest timed out

Tags: mysql, node.js, localhost, sequelize.js

- I'm using nodeJs Express Framework.
- I'm using mysql database with sequelizejs library and using querying for retrieve data.

I am getting timeout error when I fired select query for almost 50,00,000 records.

I have done the server timeout but not worked.
I have done the pooling method in sequlizeJs But not worked.

```
function fetchNamesData(req, name) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const names = req.app.locals.models.names_data;
        names.findAll({
            where: {
                name: name
            },
            order: [['date', 'DESC']],
            limit: 50
        })
            .then(function (dbRes) {
                console.log(dbRes.length);
                resolve(dbRes);
            })
            .catch(function (dbErr) {
                console.log(dbErr);
                return reject(dbErr);
            });
    });
}

allNames.forEach(element => {
//console.log(element.dataValues.name);
fetchNamesData(req, element.dataValues.name).then((dbRes) => {
//here I will have all the records
}).catch((dbErr) => { console.log(dbErr) });
```

var allNames = {having almost 7000 names}
now I iterate this obj and each names having 50 record in database
I want to get that all record like 50*7000 = 3,50,000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution like 
- Remove the unwanted console.log() and 
 
- Also your hardware configuration depend upon it for timeout error. 
 
- When query is firing do not start or run any other work it will lead to time out error[when there are multiple crud operation is going on].
- Also give index to table field when particular field is going to use in where clause.

Answer (score 0):

**What happens in your case is :**

Looping through 7000 names and at same time hitting 7000 queries in mySql , and mysql will create queue for executing 7000 queries at same time cause load on machine. Either you can update your configuration to handle such load OR

**Solution to this :** Try to put some timeout b/w each queries , this way you will be able to fetch more records ,

```
allNames.forEach(element => {
    setTimeout(() => { // <----------- HERE -------------
        fetchNamesData(req, element.dataValues.name).then((dbRes) => {
            //here I will have all the records
        }).catch((dbErr) => {
            console.log(dbErr)
        });
    },500); // <----------- HERE -------------
});
```

Comment: thank you for answering Vivek but I don't want to loose any single sec while retrieving data. and your suggestion will cost me like 16 days If I'm not wrong about calculation...

Comment: but I've tried it but no luck..still I'm getting this error